# Doxygen documentation for multiple parameters

Tags: c++, doxygen

How can I create a documentation for a group of functions which have different parameters (but I want them to share the same documentation) ?

I tried

```
/// @brief ...
/// 
/// @{
void func1(int a);
void func2(float b, void *c);
/// @}
```

but that is redundantly putting the documentation on each function, plus doxygen is warning me if I try to document a parameter.

If I use DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC to false then it's working but just func1 is clickable, not the other ones.

Comment: One approach would be to use `@copydoc`.  It's not quite what you're after but does mean there's only one instance of the documentation, which is presumably the underlying aim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @name on a line before @brief to create a Member Group.

```
/// @name
/// @brief
/// Description of two functions
/// @{
void func1(int a);
void func2(float b, void *c);
/// @}
```

If the functions are related in a way that you can summarize briefly, you can add a descriptive name after the @name tag.